# my jquery ajax does not work in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Want To Send Data Via Jquery Ajax In Asp.Net MVC

But When The Function create Was Called The Error Section Excuted

Here My Java Script

```
    function create() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action(actionName:"Create",controllerName:"Tag",routeValues:new { Area="Admin"})",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                eval(response.Script);
            }, error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

Here Is My Action Method

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken,HttpPost, AjaxOnly]
    public ActionResult Create(Tag tag)
    {            
        JsonData data = new JsonData();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TagOperation.Where(x => x.Text == tag.Text) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    TagOperation.Add(tag);
                    data.Script = MessageBox.Show("Message", MessageType.Success).Script;
                    return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Tag", routeValues: new { Area = "Admin" });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    data.Script = MessageBox.Show("Message", MessageType.Error).Script;
                    return Json(data);
                }
            }
        }
        data.Script = MessageBox.Show(ModelState.GetErrors(), MessageType.Warning).Script;
        return Json(data);
    }
```

And Here Is My View That Send Data Via Jquery Ajax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tag", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">        
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input onclick="create();" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Start by removing `contentType: "application/json",` And if that is not working, explain what error you getting. You have multiple errors. Ajax calls do not redirect so `return RedirectToAction()` is pointless. `MessageBox.Show()` is WinForms, not MVC

Comment: I Remove contentType But It Does Not Work And I Get 500 Status Code And The Error Title's is required anti-forgery form field... I Put ValidateAntiForgeryToken And Html.AntiForgery In My Form.And MessageBox Is My Own Class For Generate JavaScript

Comment: `500(Internal Server Error)` means your controller code is throwing and exception. And what do you mean you put `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` in the form? - that's an attribute that's applied to the controller method.

Comment: Yes But It Was Entered Into My Action I Have Break Point But It Was Not Enter My Break Point

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [HttpPost] attribute to your action result method (by default action results use GET)

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Create(Tag tag){..}
```

Comment: I Put This Attributes ValidateAntiForgeryToken , HttpPost And It Does Not Work

Comment: Can you provide the 500(Internal Server Error) message  that the code is throwing ?

Comment: Yes I Recive 500 Code From Server

Comment: I Recive This "The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present."

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try adding the token to the request header.

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

var headers = {};

headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;

$.ajax({
        headers: headers,
});
```

Comment: It Does Not Work. The Exception Was Thrown Is The Same As Before